# window blocked when the application is running c#

Tags: c#

I have a small application coded on c# (Windows Form)(visual stud 2012)
when I run the application it work properly except that when the application is running i can't no more  click on the window or even move it, until it finish the process
how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Move the work to a separate thread. Search here for `[c#] Background worker`.

Comment: So the thread is busy. Hmm. Could you share the code you are using that is taking up the thread? Maybe we can give some pointers.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement the [BackgroundWorker Control/Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

To do this, just drag the control `BackgroundWorker` from the toolbox on to the form. Select the background worker you just created and double-click on it. Now put all the code you need to do separately from the UI into this event.

Example:

```
//Assuming we have a background worker called backgroundWorker
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {

     //put code here

}
```

Now in the triggering block of code, call `backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()`.

Example:

```
private buttonDoWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); 
}
```

Just be careful and be [threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848067/what-makes-a-method-thread-safe-what-are-the-rules).

Comment: woooow !!! it's fixed now :D
Thank you 
i will try to make the same thing to fix the progress bar update

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

> Executes an operation on a separate thread.
>
> The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a
>   separate, dedicated thread. Time-consuming operations like downloads
>   and database transactions can cause your user interface (UI) to seem
>   as though it has stopped responding while they are running. When you
>   want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated
>   with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a convenient
>   solution.

Comment: Threads again :(
i'm not so good on the thread things, but i will try to have an idea about it (i was trying to make a progress bar with a thread but finally i let it down)

Comment: I don't know how to put my code on the :
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {}
because the method that take a lot of time is called when the user click on a button

    public partial class Welcome : Form
    {
        private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1;
       public Welcome()
        {
          }

       private void Button3Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //call a method that take a lot of time 
         }
      }

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are doing your processing on the UI Thread.  Any processing you do on the UI thread takes away cycles that User Interface events can be serviced.