# Running parallel tasks c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, async-await

In a windows store app project i have a function that i call several times inside a foreach cycle to fill in some objects

The method header looks like this

```
private async Task createInvite(JsonValue item, string meetingid, List<MeetingInvitee> listInvitees)
```

i was trying to run this in parallel tasks like so

```
List<Task> ts = new List<Task>();
foreach (JsonValue item in invitees)
{
    ts.Add(createInvite(item, meetingid, listInvitees));
}

await Task.WhenAll(ts);
```

but it seems it doesnt create tasks that run at all at same time. this takes about 10 seconds.

if instead i use this

```
//List<Task> ts = new List<Task>();
foreach (JsonValue item in invitees)
{
    //ts.Add(createInvite(item, meetingid, listInvitees));
      await createInvite(item, meetingid, listInvitees);
}

//await Task.WhenAll(ts);
```

it also takes about 10 seconds.

Am i not running several tasks at same time with my first option?

**Edit**

```
private async Task createInvite(JsonValue item, string meetingid, List<MeetingInvitee> listInvitees)
{
    try
    {

        Stopwatch st = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        MeetingInvitee org = new MeetingInvitee();
        MeetingInvitee altorg = new MeetingInvitee();
        JsonObject invitee2;
        JsonObject invitee;
        InviteeDB InviteeForDB = new InviteeDB();
        GappService gappservice = new GappService();

        MeetingInvitee inv = new MeetingInvitee();


        JsonObject.TryParse(item.Stringify(), out invitee2);

        invitee = invitee2["user"].GetObject();



        if (invitee2.ContainsKey("_id"))
        {
            inv.id = invitee2["_id"].GetString();
            InviteeForDB.Id = invitee2["_id"].GetString();
        }
        else
        {
            InviteeForDB.Id = invitee2["user"].GetString();
        }

        if (invitee2.ContainsKey("status"))
        {
            if (invitee2["status"].ValueType == JsonValueType.Null)
            {
                inv.status = string.Empty;
                InviteeForDB.Status = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                inv.status = invitee2["status"].GetString();
                InviteeForDB.Status = invitee2["status"].GetString();
            }
        }
        Stopwatch st2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        if (invitee2.ContainsKey("user"))
        {

            if (invitee2["user"].ValueType != JsonValueType.Null)
            {
                User iUser = new User();
                //iUser.Id = InviteeForDB.UserID;

                JsonSerializerSettings sett = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                sett.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                iUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(invitee.Stringify(), sett);

                inv.user = iUser;
            }
            else
                return;
        }
        else
            return;

        InviteeForDB.MeetingID = meetingid;
        ds.inviteeRepository.Add(InviteeForDB);
        listInvitees.Add(inv);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`Parallel.For()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Is your code actually async?

Comment: Show us your `createInvite` method.

Comment: Your current code is producing a compiler warning explaining exactly what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't actually async (it has no `await` statements), so all of the work is happening in initial `createInvite()` call inside the `for` loop.

You can make that actually run in parallel using `Parallel.ForEach()`, but that will break your code, because it isn't actually thread-safe.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing truly async about your method. Simply adding the `async` modifier doesn't magically make this async, or execute in *parallel* which is what I think you're trying to do. All it does is signal the compiler that a state-machine needs to be generated. This code, as is, will execute completely synchronously.

You can explicitly invoke your method on a thread-pool thread using `Task.Run` or `Parallel.ForEach`, but looking at your code it doesn't look as if it would be thread-safe at all to do that. Before going any further, try to isolate `CreateInvite` to actually be thread-safe, then look into one of the options mentioned above.

Comment: any tips on how to do that?

Comment: Make your code thread-safe? You could start by eliminating global variables and making everything local to the method call. And [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848067/what-makes-a-method-thread-safe-what-are-the-rules)