# New thread in singleton never finished

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have simple singleton class:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public class MySingleton
    {
        static MySingleton()
        {
        }

        private static readonly MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();
        private  bool threadFinished = false;
        public bool IsReady = false;

        private MySingleton()
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(MyAction);
            t.Start();

            while (!threadFinished)
               Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        public static MySingleton Instance
        {
            get { return instance; }
        }

        private void MyAction()
        {
            threadFinished = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm trying instatiate this by:

```
var ir =  MySingleton.Instance.IsReady;
```

it never ends - the while loop is infinite. Why? And how to run backround thread in singleton at constructor?

Comment: It could work to declare threadFinished as volatile but please google for a better singleton pattern instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.  I am not a Singleton expert - if this violates any rules, someone please point it out.  But this gets around the deadlock.  I copied your code into a console app, if you're using it elsewhere, adjust appropriately.

```
namespace TestApp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (!MySingleton.Instance.IsReady)
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class MySingleton
{
    static MySingleton()
    {
    }

    private static readonly MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();
    private static bool threadFinished = false;
    public bool IsReady
    {
        get { return threadFinished; }       
    }

    private MySingleton()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyAction));

        t.Start();
    }

    public static MySingleton Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }
    static void MyAction()
    {
        threadFinished = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're deadlocking. You're not allowed to call any methods from another thread before the static constructor is executed. Static constructor includes the static field initalizers too.

Since you're blocking the calling thread with a while loop, static field initialization will not complete and the new thread will neither be permitted to execute `MyAction` either.

Your code is almost identical to [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8883117/2530848) where Eric demonstrates the deadlock.

And to quote eric's comment from same answer why does it deadlock:

> @Lieven: The static constructor must run no more than once and it
>   must run before the first call to any static method in the class. Main
>   is a static method, so the main thread calls the static ctor. To
>   ensure it only runs once, the CLR takes out a lock that is not
>   released until the static ctor finishes. When the ctor starts a new
>   thread, that thread also calls a static method, so the CLR tries to
>   take the lock to see if it needs to run the ctor. The main thread
>   meanwhile "joins" the blocked thread, and now we have our deadlock. –
>   Eric Lippert Jan 17 '12 at 14:28

To answer your question; Don't do that. You gain nothing by starting a thread and waiting for it. Just simply run the method synchronously.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. But I need to start new Thread - and than run code on it's SynchornizationContext. So what is the best solution for start new backround thread only once?

Comment: Why it has to be in another thread? I don't see the exact problem. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: That new Thread execute WebCore.Run() from http://docs.awesomium.net/html/M_Awesomium_Core_WebCore_Run.htm So that thread is blocked as specified in doc. WebCore,Run() is blocking thread which on it is executed so I need to create new and run WebCore.Run() only once. After I get SynchronizationContext.Current it is used in Parallel loop

Comment: You can start it in another thread. But don't wait for it. i.e just removing the `while (!threadFinished)` should work. Am I missing something?

Comment: It doesn't because myContext (the new Thread set it from SynchronizationContext.Current) is null until WebCore is Initialized - it takes 1-2 sek. So I need to wait for WebCore Initilization. MyAction() contains `WebCore.Started += (s, e) =>
            {
                myContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;   
            };` After removing `while` myContext.Send() throws exception

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [lock statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) when you create an instance of your singleton to make it thread safe.

An example of how to use it in the singleton pattern can be found here: http://www.dofactory.com/net/singleton-design-pattern